# Is it grammatically correct to use "with having" in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Please, can explain to me the right way to use "with" and "having" in the same sentence, if it's possible to use. For example:

> What business can I start with having 20k?

Is this the correct usage, or no?

Comment: The words "with" and "having" both have the same function, so having both in the sentence is redundant and incorrect. It's like, "I threw the ball to towards Mark."

Answer (score 1):

What business can I start with R$20k?

You might also say,

Having R$20k, what business can I start?

You don't need both words together to describe how much capital you have.